# Electron- ipc sendSync - Returning event.returnValue inside a callback

Tags: javascript, electron

In my renderer process (web page),I am sending a message synchronously for printing the page as PDF.

In the callback of `window.webContents.printToPDF` I am returning the returnValue of event.But the callback is never called.I used VSCode to confirm this.

When attempting the same process asynchronously it works fine.

**Code:**

*Renderer:*

```
var params = {
    "path": undefined,
    "filename": vm.profile._id + " " + vm.profile.firstname
}
let result = ipcRenderer.sendSync('print-profile-pdf', params);
```

*Main Process:*

```
ipcMain.on('print-profile-pdf', function(event, params) {
    printToPdf(params.path, params.filename, event);
});
function printToPdf(path, filename, event) {
    var options = {
        marginsType: 2,
        pageSize: "A4",
        printBackground: false,
        printSelectionOnly: false,
        landscape: false
    };
    let file = (path || app.getPath("desktop")) + "/" + (filename || "profile") + ".pdf";
    previewWindow.webContents.printToPDF(options, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            logger.error(error);
            event.returnValue = {
                error: error,
                success: false
            };
            throw error;
        }
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                logger.error(error);
                event.returnValue = {
                    error: error,
                    success: false
                };
                throw error;
            }
            logger.info("PDF Saved Successfully in " + filename);
            event.returnValue = {
                filename: filename + ".pdf",
                success: true
            };
        });
    });
};
```

**UPDATE:**

- **OS:** Windows 10,Windows 7
- **Electron Version:** 0.37.4

**Demo of issue:**

https://github.com/RaghuChandrasekaran/electron-quick-start

1. Clone the repo
2. Run application and click on print to pdf

Comment: I am not able to duplicate. Do you see any errors in the Dev Tools when your code is run in the renderer process?

Comment: @ShawnRakowski I was able to duplicate same error in a fresh environment.I have updated the question with the repo url and more details.Please look into it.

Comment: I see your dilemma now, I misunderstood what was failing to be called. I haven't found anything to confirm this, but my intuition tells me that the webcontent.printToPDF requires the renderer process's thread to be available to perform this activity but is stuck waiting for a response from the sendSync() call. What is the requirement that is driving it being synchronous?

Comment: @ShawnRakowski The reason I wanted synchronous execution is not to allow the user to interact until print operation gets successfully executed.But after this issue cropped up I reverted back to the use of async call and used other UI means to restrict user actions.But since this issue (may be expected behaviour) is existing I wanted to have a better insight on it.